# How to force reloading of a customer data section?

Tags: magento2, cache, customer-data

I'm using CustomerData library to display private content ([Magento docs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/cache/page-caching/private-content.html)).

I see that in `etc/frontend/sections.xml` I can configure which requests would result in requesting the data from the server and storing in browser's local storage.

Is there a way to specifically ask to invalidate the data (the particular section)? For example, I want to request it if a data property is absent or if a data property had been received more than 1 hour ago.

Do I make a dedicated dummy action that does nothing just so I could add it to `etc/frontend/sections.xml` and a request by AJAX when I need to invalidate the section cache, or is there some better way?

If this is the solution, then **why should I bother with the customer data at all?** I could just make that AJAX call return the data I need and store it the local storage myself.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is no easy way to invalidate data from backend.
On frontend you can use
`app/code/Magento/Customer/view/frontend/web/js/customer-data.js` library to invalidate the local storage. Just call `customerData.reload(['section_name']);`

In crhome console it will look like: `require('Magento_Customer/js/customer-data').reload(['customer']);`

Comment: Is there an option to reload customer data in php? do you know?

Comment: @JulianoVargas Did you find any way to do that on the server side?

Comment: @Pini I haven't investigated it any further!

Comment: Yes! This - Thank you so much for providing a very exact example on how to run it from the console. Don't ever stop doing that :)

Comment: @JulianoVargas if you need to invalidate the cache from backend you need to send `private_content_version` cookie with some random value. However, this way works only on POST requests initiated by the consumer. There is no way to invalidate private cache for many customers from admin panel.

Comment: the section name argument in the `reload()` method is array, not a string so this is correct: `require('Magento_Customer/js/customer-data').reload(['customer']);`

Comment: Really very helpful you saved my day. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, You can do this by reloading on the front end side by calling the customerData from:

`Magento_Customer/js/customer-data.js`

and do something like this:

`let sections = ['name_section'];
customerData.invalidate(sections);
customerData.reload(sections, true);`