# magento 2: addErrorMessage in cms page not work when enable cache

Tags: magento2, messages

I'm trying adderrormessage to the cms page, but I have to disable the cache and it will work. I would like to enable the cache adderrormessage still working.

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http $response,
    \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager,
    \Vendor\Module\Helper\ModuleConfig $moduleConfig
)
{
    $this->response = $response;
    $this->_messageManager = $messageManager;
    $this->moduleConfig = $moduleConfig;
}

public function addErroMessage(){
    $errorMessage = $this->moduleConfig->getErrorMessage();
    $this->_messageManager->addErrorMessage($errorMessage);
    $pageId = $this->moduleConfig->getPageIdToRedirect();
    $urlPage = $this->helperCmsPage->getPageUrl($pageId);
    $this->response->setRedirect($urlPage);
}
```

enable cache: not work
[image]

disable cache: work
[image]
Someone know the answer please help me! Thank you very much!

Comment: When cache is enabled, the cms page is only "rendered" once, by the server. Rest of the times it's being served from the cache. What you could do is __hole-punching__ and make the `page.messages` block non cacheable. But what is it that you're trying to achieve? Why do you need session messages to be displayed in a CMS page? Which is almost always static

Comment: Thank you Jay Ghosh for comment. I'm doing the function when the wrong path redirect to cms page and display errorMessage. Is there a solution to display errorMessage non the cacheable? Thank you!

Comment: Put in the session message, and then refresh your "messages" section in your page. Take a look at this to understand how to refresh a customer data section https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/208223/how-to-force-reloading-of-a-customer-data-section