# Magento 2: Customer name not display in programmatically logged in user account

Tags: magento2.3, customer-account, login, header, customer-name

I have programmatically logged into the customer accounts from my custom controller. In this case the customer name is not loading in the header. 
https://prnt.sc/nzucg9

How can I do it?

Here is the code

```
    public function __construct(
               .....
            \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterfaceFactory $customerInterfaceFactory,
            \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManagerInterface,
            \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepositoryInterface,
            \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory,
            \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
             ....
        ) {
            $this->customerInterfaceFactory = $customerInterfaceFactory;
            $this->customerRepositoryInterface = $customerRepositoryInterface;
            $this->storeManagerInterface = $storeManagerInterface;
            $this->customerFactory = $customerFactory;
            $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
                 .....

        }

 public function execute() {
    $email = 'test@test.com';
        $storeId = $this->storeManagerInterface->getStore()->getId();             
        $websiteId = $this->storeManagerInterface->getStore($storeId)->getWebsiteId();      
        $customer = $this->customerFactory->create();
        $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId)->loadByEmail($email);
        $this->customerSession->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer);
        $this->customerSession->regenerateId();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That value comes from localstorage (stored in the browser), you should check that your code actually places/reloads the customer data in the localstorage, that can hardly be done from the backend, try to use js to interact with the local storage, take this answer:
[How to force reloading of a customer data section?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/208223/how-to-force-reloading-of-a-customer-data-section)

> There is no easy way to invalidate data from backend. On frontend you
>   can use
>   app/code/Magento/Customer/view/frontend/web/js/customer-data.js
>   library to invalidate the local storage. Just call
>   customerData.reload(['section_name']);
>
> In crhome console it will look like:
>   require('Magento_Customer/js/customer-data').reload('customer');

Also you can use this module as an example on how they implement the localstorage reload: 
https://github.com/magefan/module-login-as-customer

Comment: I have used an ajax function to login to the account. I want to set the localstorage in the success function. How can I do it?

Comment: Check the answer now, haven't tried it but other people did it like that

Comment: I have tried it. But it is not working

Comment: It seems that you should interact with the local storage trough the frontend, check: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/208223/how-to-force-reloading-of-a-customer-data-section

Also check this free module, they use a js to reload the customer data: 
https://github.com/magefan/module-login-as-customer

I'm using that module and works perfectly

Comment: Thank you so much SantiBM. The extension js works perfectly. Please  update the answer.

Comment: Great news! Just updated it